# gunicorn[15246]: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, geckodriver

I'm currently trying to run a python script using selenium and geckodriver on an Ubuntu 20.04 server. I'm using gunicorn and nginx to setup my flask application, but I've been trying for days now to use every answer on all similar articles, but still nothing is working for me as it is for others.

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Firefox version – Mozilla Firefox 81.0

Selenium version - 3.141.0

Geckodriver version – 0.27.0

**Code: (I've tried each of these 6 below)**

```
def login(self):
    try:
        print("Logging in...")
        # 1)
        ff_options = FirefoxOptions()
        ff_options.headless = True
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=ff_options)

        # 2)
        ff_options = FirefoxOptions()
        ff_options.headless = True
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="./geckodriver", options=ff_options)

        # 3)
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

        # 4)
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox('./geckodriver')

        # 5)
        binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

        # 6)
        binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="/home/ubuntu/cole/instagram_bot_v2")

        self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')
```

**Error I'm receiving:**

```
Oct 12 07:00:11 ip-172-31-32-84 gunicorn[15245]: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

The geckodriver executable itself I've tried placing in /usr/bin, /usr/local/bin and also just in my project directory, all are set to executable, but it doesn't seem to make a difference when running it, they all get the same path error.

Anyone have any ideas what I could try?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is to move your `geckodriver` to the same directory where your program is saved. Then, you can start the `geckodriver` just by using `webdriver.Firefox()` instead of specifying the full path of the executable file. This would save you a lot of time.

Comment: I've just changed to this setup now, and unfortunately still receiving the "Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH." error :/

I've added this directory into my system variables too, with the command export PATH=$PATH:/home/ubuntu/cole/instagram_bot_v2